# how to select values from popup window in ruby scripting

Tags: watir

I am testing my application using Watir.Application contains popup window where i have to select the value and set that value to some field in parent window .can any one suggest how to write ruby script to select value from popup window and set to field in parent window.

Comment: an example of the HTML for the popup (or that creates the popup) would be useful.  in fact pretty much essential, since there are many different types of 'pop=ups' that we could be talking about and pulling information from, or interacting with them will be different depending on what type of popup it is.

Answer (score 2):

This could help: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Pop+Ups

Comment: start with the stuff at the link above, and at least figure out what kind of 'popup' you are dealing with.